# Find where an item belongs in a sorted list

Tags: java, android, algorithm, list, sorting

I have a sorted by first name array list:

```
[0] Abe Lock
[1] Christine Wilson
[2] John Daily
[3] Rita Butler
```

I want to insert the name "Henry Bosh" using the java ArrayList method: `add(int index, E element)`. What is the most efficient way to find the index of where to put "Henry Bosh" and still have the arraylist sorted?

Comment: Why a `List`? Why not directly use a `SortedSet` instead? Unless you expect to have duplicate entries?

Comment: @fge i need it as a list so i can put it in my array adapter for android

Comment: [Collections.binarySearch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,%20T))

Comment: I don't know what an "array adapter" is, but if this is a Java array, `Collection` (and therefore, by extension, `Set` and `SortedSet`) has a `.toArray()` method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way if the list is already sorted is to use binary search. Java has a built in binary search for collections you might be able to use:

```
arraylist.add(Collections.binarySearch(arraylist, newString), newString)
```

should work if you don't expect duplicates, otherwise you might have to make a custom binary search function

also you might need to modify the compareTo function for your list